# "Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" on QtCreator project

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors

I'm getting the error

```
Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Trying to compile a project on QtCreator. It happens when I try to create an instance of an user defined class, `Layer`. That class consists of a header, `layer.h`, and a implementation, `layer.cpp`. It was tested and works in another programs. On my project, it is included in `qtwidget.h` and the error happens when I try to use it on `qtwidget.cpp`. For example:

```
Layer<double> text("pq.txt",0.5,0.5,0.5);
```

Having this line on `qtwidget.cpp` is enough for the error to show up.

This is such a generic error that I'm clueless on how to isolate it any further, but if it helps, I've included the whole project on [this git repo](http://github.com/viclib/3d_multilayer_viewer).

Answer (score 54):

In my opinion, the error message that Qt Creator displays is quite misleading until you understand it, but does not prevent splitting the template class into a header and implementation file. If you think about the message:

```
Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

the problem, I originally thought when I saw this, is that it states this error on its own in the *Issues* output and can lead the user into thinking that the problem is due to the architecture. Actually, all its saying is that there's a defined symbol (often function) whose matching implementation wasn't found.

If you change from *Issues* to the *Compile Output* window and scroll up, you'll be able to see exactly what symbols can't be found; mine's displayed in red. It's just annoying that the detail of the missing symbol(s) doesn't show up in the *Issues* view.

It's easy to replicate this error by just adding a function definition into a header and without implementing the function, call it from the .cpp file. You'll then see something like this in the Issues window

[image: symbol not found]

Switching to the Compile Output view and scrolling up displays this: -

[image]

So now we see that tthe actual problem is that the function DoSomeStuff in the class called PGGui is being called from the constructor PGGui::PGGui, but the body of DoSomeStuff is missing, as its symbol is not found.

Comment: This was my problem too. I had a few slots that I had forgotten to define. Thanks. (:

Comment: When I declare public slots in .h file yet haven't define the slots in .cpp file, this error rises.

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately I've managed to solve my problem before any answers, so, if anyone is experiencing anything similar, the issue was that it seems you **can't split a templated class into a .cpp and a .h file**. Putting all declarations of the `.cpp` file back into the `.h` solved the issue.

I still had a leftover problem, though: duplicated symbols (which was the reason I split it). This time, declaring a variable as `external` in the `.h`, and redeclaring it without the `external` keyword in one (and only one) `.cpp` file solved the issue for good.

Answer (score 2):

For me this problem resulted from not rebuilding the make file after adding another source file and header.

Under Build: 
Cleanall->run qMake->run

fixed the error for me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in my case was that i had a project with many subproject and one of the pro files of the subprojects was empty.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I forgot to write the name of the class object when declaring the function in .cpp file.

wrong: `int Zero(int &num)`

right: `int Common2::Zero(int &num)`

Where Common2 is the class.