# Qt symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, qt

First of all I am new to Qt, so if there may be something painstakingly obvious to some more advanced users, I also know this error crops up a lot and I've done a lot of reading on Qt forums and have still not managed to solve my problem.

I don't however understand why I am even getting the `symbols not found for architecture x86_64` error as I had been working on my application all day without any problems.

I am building an image editor in the likes of Photoshop for an assignment in my Cross Platform SW Development course at Uni and wanted to separate the filter logic I was writing from the rest of my code, I therefore created a `Filters` class.

In my `mainwindow.h` I created a private reference to the class `Filters *filter;` which I instantiated  in `mainwindow.cpp`

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
     QMainWindow(parent),
     ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
     // Instanciate a scene object that we can draw to and then set up the ui
     scene  = new QGraphicsScene(this);
     filter = new Filters(this);
     ui->setupUi(this);
     QObject::connect(ui->cmdBlack_White, SIGNAL(triggered()), filter, SLOT(serialFilterBlackWhite(image)));
}
```

As you can see, I have created a connection to the `serialFilterBlackWhite` method, which resides in `filters.cpp` at the moment and doesn't do much due to the x86 error:

```
QPixmap Filters::serialFilterBlackWhite(QPixmap image)
{
   image.fill( Qt::red );
   return image;
}
```

The `.h` file for the class looks like this :

```
#ifndef FILTERS_H
#define FILTERS_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QPixmap>

class Filters : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Filters(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    QPixmap serialFilterBlackWhite(QPixmap);

};

#endif // FILTERS_H
```

I have tried not too bloat my question with too much code, but if you need more please let me know.  I really have no idea whats going on with this.

Comment: It [seems that this (misleading) error message is produced when you have an undefined symbol](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18978656/21475) (i.e. a function or method that you've declared and used but have not defined).

Comment: @Cameron that looks promising, it is a very vague error message. I'll look into that answer - cheers