# Qt simple text editor, what's wrong?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning Qt basics using their text editor [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gettingstartedqt.html).

I can't figure out what's wrong with my code in main(). I'm having the following errors:

> linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Here's my code:

```
class TextEditor : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TextEditor();

private slots:
    void quit();

private:
    QTextEdit *textEdit;
    QPushButton *quitButton;
};

TextEditor::TextEditor()
{
    textEdit = new QTextEdit;
    quitButton = new QPushButton(tr("Quit"));

    connect(quitButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(quit()));

    QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    layout->addWidget(textEdit);
    layout->addWidget(quitButton);

    setLayout(layout);

    setWindowTitle(tr("TextEditor"));
}

void TextEditor::quit()
{
    QMessageBox messageBox;
    messageBox.setWindowTitle(tr("TextEditor"));
    messageBox.setText(tr("Really?"));
    messageBox.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox::Yes | QMessageBox::No);
    messageBox.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox::No);
    if (messageBox.exec() == QMessageBox::Yes)
        qApp->quit();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    TextEditor w;
    w.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: You are trying to link against 32bit libraries when you should be linking against the 64 bit ones.

Comment: What is the environment you are trying to build this in?

Comment: @LahiruChandima I'm using QtCreator. MacBook Air OSX Yosemite 10.10.1.

Comment: possible duplicate of ["Symbol(s) not found for architecture x86\_64" on QtCreator project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973042/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-on-qtcreator-project)

Comment: Check whether you have any linker errors in Compiler Output pane in the bottom

Comment: I think what you're posting is not the complete error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add following to the bottom of the source file.

```
#include "main.moc"
```

Then do `build->run qmake` and then `build->rebuild`