# build LLVM example: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: gcc, compiler-construction, clang, llvm

I've installed LLVM on my laptop but having problem compiling the `Fibonacci` example in `llvm/examples/Fibonacci`:

> clang++ -std=c++11 -I ../../include fibonacci.cpp -o fib

```
/usr/local/include/llvm/Support/DataTypes.h:57:3: error: "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
```

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965870/error-must-define-stdc-limit-macros-before-including-support-datatypes-h), I add some driver flags:

> clang++ fibonacci.cpp -std=c++11 -I ../../include -o fib -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS

Different errors produced:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LLVMInitializeX86Target", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTarget() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTarget() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTarget() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "_LLVMLinkInInterpreter", referenced from:
      (anonymous namespace)::ForceInterpreterLinking::ForceInterpreterLinking() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::BasicBlock::BasicBlock(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Function*, llvm::BasicBlock*)", referenced from:
      llvm::BasicBlock::Create(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Function*, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::BranchInst::BranchInst(llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::Value*, llvm::BasicBlock*)", referenced from:
      llvm::BranchInst::Create(llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::Value*, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::ReturnInst::ReturnInst(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Value*, llvm::BasicBlock*)", referenced from:
      llvm::ReturnInst::Create(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Value*, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::VectorType::get(llvm::Type*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      llvm::CmpInst::makeCmpResultType(llvm::Type*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::IntegerType*, unsigned long long, bool)", referenced from:
      CreateFibFunction(llvm::Module*, llvm::LLVMContext&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Instruction::Instruction(llvm::Type*, unsigned int, llvm::Use*, unsigned int, llvm::BasicBlock*)", referenced from:
      llvm::CallInst::CallInst(llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::OperandBundleDefT<llvm::Value*> >, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Instruction::~Instruction()", referenced from:
      llvm::CmpInst::~CmpInst() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::CallInst::CallInst(llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::OperandBundleDefT<llvm::Value*> >, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::LLVMContext::LLVMContext()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::LLVMContext::~LLVMContext()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::raw_ostream::write(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(llvm::StringRef) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(long)", referenced from:
      llvm::raw_ostream::operator<<(int) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::verifyModule(llvm::Module const&, llvm::raw_ostream*)", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::selectTarget()", referenced from:
      llvm::EngineBuilder::create() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::create(llvm::TargetMachine*)", referenced from:
      llvm::EngineBuilder::create() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::EngineBuilder(std::__1::unique_ptr<llvm::Module, std::__1::default_delete<llvm::Module> >)", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::~EngineBuilder()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::BinaryOperator::Create(llvm::Instruction::BinaryOps, llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*)", referenced from:
      llvm::BinaryOperator::CreateSub(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::BinaryOperator::CreateAdd(llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::llvm_unreachable_internal(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      llvm::User::operator delete(void*, unsigned int) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(llvm::LLVMContext&)", referenced from:
      CreateFibFunction(llvm::Module*, llvm::LLVMContext&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Type::getInt1Ty(llvm::LLVMContext&)", referenced from:
      llvm::CmpInst::makeCmpResultType(llvm::Type*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::User::operator delete(void*)", referenced from:
      CreateFibFunction(llvm::Module*, llvm::LLVMContext&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::ICmpInst::~ICmpInst() in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
     (maybe you meant: __ZN4llvm4UserdlEPvj)
  "llvm::User::operator new(unsigned long, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      llvm::CmpInst::operator new(unsigned long) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::BranchInst::Create(llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::BasicBlock*, llvm::Value*, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::ReturnInst::Create(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Value*, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::CallInst::Create(llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::errs()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::outs()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::APInt::initSlowCase(unsigned int, unsigned long long, bool)", referenced from:
      llvm::APInt::APInt(unsigned int, unsigned long long, bool) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Value::setName(llvm::Twine const&)", referenced from:
      CreateFibFunction(llvm::Module*, llvm::LLVMContext&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Module::getOrInsertFunction(llvm::StringRef, llvm::Type*, ...)", referenced from:
      CreateFibFunction(llvm::Module*, llvm::LLVMContext&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Module::Module(llvm::StringRef, llvm::LLVMContext&)", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Module::~Module()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::CmpInst::anchor()", referenced from:
      vtable for llvm::ICmpInst in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::CmpInst::CmpInst(llvm::Type*, llvm::Instruction::OtherOps, unsigned short, llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*)", referenced from:
      llvm::ICmpInst::ICmpInst(llvm::BasicBlock&, llvm::CmpInst::Predicate, llvm::Value*, llvm::Value*, llvm::Twine const&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::CallInst::init(llvm::FunctionType*, llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::OperandBundleDefT<llvm::Value*> >, llvm::Twine const&)", referenced from:
      llvm::CallInst::init(llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::OperandBundleDefT<llvm::Value*> >, llvm::Twine const&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Type::getScalarType() const", referenced from:
      llvm::Type::isIntOrIntVectorTy() const in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
      llvm::Type::isPtrOrPtrVectorTy() const in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::APInt::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, bool) const", referenced from:
      llvm::operator<<(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::APInt const&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Module::print(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::AssemblyAnnotationWriter*, bool, bool) const", referenced from:
      llvm::operator<<(llvm::raw_ostream&, llvm::Module const&) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "llvm::Function::BuildLazyArguments() const", referenced from:
      llvm::Function::CheckLazyArguments() const in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "typeinfo for llvm::CmpInst", referenced from:
      typeinfo for llvm::ICmpInst in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  "vtable for llvm::CallInst", referenced from:
      llvm::CallInst::CallInst(llvm::Value*, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::Value*>, llvm::ArrayRef<llvm::OperandBundleDefT<llvm::Value*> >, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::BasicBlock*) in fibonacci-1b0cd0.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I keep searching and find a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31152499/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64-stdterminate-when-building-kal). Another shot:

> clang++ -g -O3 fibonacci.cpp `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core` -o fib

Much shorter errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LLVMInitializeX86Target", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetInfo", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86TargetMC", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "_LLVMLinkInInterpreter", referenced from:
      __GLOBAL__sub_I_fibonacci.cpp in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::selectTarget()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::create(llvm::TargetMachine*)", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::EngineBuilder(std::__1::unique_ptr<llvm::Module, std::__1::default_delete<llvm::Module> >)", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
  "llvm::EngineBuilder::~EngineBuilder()", referenced from:
      _main in fibonacci-21f462.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The executables of `llvm/build/bin` generated by CMake auto-build are good, which might prove the tool chain is working.

But I still want to go into the code and observe.

Could someone help me out?

```
LLVM version 3.8.0svn
Default target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Host CPU: has well

clang version 3.8.0 
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

---

update:

I build a do-nothing `a-test.cpp`:

```
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/GenericValue.h"
#include "llvm/ExecutionEngine/Interpreter.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Constants.h"
#include "llvm/IR/DerivedTypes.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Instructions.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/Support/TargetSelect.h"
#include "llvm/Support/raw_ostream.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

and successfully compile:

> clang++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 a-test.cpp `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core executionengine interpreter mc support nativecodegen` -o a-test
>
> ./a-test

```
hello world
```

but not so good for `fibonacci.cpp`:

> clang++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 fibonacci.cpp `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core executionengine interpreter mc support nativecodegen` -o fib

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "typeinfo for llvm::CmpInst", referenced from:
      typeinfo for llvm::ICmpInst in fibonacci-009ddf.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang-3.8: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: .. I answered this in another question you asked, which was basically the same, but you deleted the question (and my answer, bit rude!) -- what's wrong with using the built in ninja target `ninja Fibonnaci`. If you want to see the exact command line, look at the build.log from the build system.

Comment: @dune.rocks My apology. Your answer did inspired but I get a complete one from other questions. So I should first accept your answer next time such thing happens?

Comment: @dune.rocks Could you please write an answer with instructions. I search for `build.log` and get nothing in the folder. And searching `log file` only to find `CMakeError.log`, `CMakeOutput.log` and `CMakeOutput.log`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the CMakeFile that builds Fibonacci, you'll see that it requires more than just the Core library.

It requires `Core`, `ExecutionEngine`, `Interpreter`, `MC`, `Support`, `nativecodege`. The correct `--libs` line would be `--libs core executionengine interpreter mc support nativecodegen`

The file you're looking for is `build.ninja`. If you search  in there for Fibonacci, you'll in all the information you need.

*Edit: due to the OP struggling here, I've included the edited command line as well*

```
clang++ -g -O3 -std=c++11 -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti fibonacci.cpp `llvm-config --cppflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core executionengine interpreter mc support nativecodegen` -o fib
```

It's generally easier to use `llvm-config --ldflags --libs` rather than worrying about exactly which subset you need as well, but meh.

This is not the right way do this anyway, use the build system!

Comment: Neither works: 0. Driver flag unrecognised (described in update). 1. No file with a `ninja` part found.

Comment: You've forgotten the back-quotes around llvm-config and are in fact passing the options to the compiler!

Comment: I saw the `hello world`! Still stuck on `fibonacci.cpp`

Comment: You need to pass `-fno-rtti` to get that to work. You'll also want `-fno-exceptions` now that I think about it.

Comment: A tough bingo. `-fno-exceptions` is not needed in this case.

Comment: Probably not, I just recommended `-fno-exceptions` because that's what the LLVM build system uses (and I supposed they had good reason, but it could equally well have been historical).

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. Could you please tell me more about the build file? I find nothing involved with `ninja`.

Comment: The comments are getting too long now. Ninja is a build system like Make. This question is resolved now.