# LLVM symbol lookup difficulties

Tags: c++, build, linker, llvm

I'm following along with the tutorial LLVM provides to get familiar with its IR that can be found [here](http://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/LangImpl04.html).

Unfortunately, it seems that when I add in the JIT support, the linker has some difficulty following along. Namely, I get a number of undefined symbols,

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_LLVMInitializeX86AsmParser", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser() in lexer.cc.o
  "_LLVMInitializeX86AsmPrinter", referenced from:
      llvm::InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter() in lexer.cc.o
etc.

I'm building using CMAKE using the LLVM config and can find the headers in my include directories, so I'm unsure why the symbols can't be fine. My code is [here](https://gitlab.com/MiroFurtado/kaleidoscope-llvm/-/blob/master/src/lexer.cc), but isn't too specific to the problem. I'm on MacOS.

How can I make the linker find the header files or why is it not working?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939671/8925535

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using CMake, you need to add some LLVM components. Here is an excerpt from my `CMakeLists.txt` for the same chapter.

```
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs analysis core executionengine instcombine object orcjit runtimedyld scalaropts support native)
```

Relevant links:

- [The official CMakeLists.txt for the chapter](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/master/llvm/examples/Kaleidoscope/Chapter4/CMakeLists.txt)
- [A StackOverflow question about a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33674630/build-llvm-example-undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x86-64)
- [The example CMakeLists.txt from the documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html#embedding-llvm-in-your-project)