# How to link all LLVM libraries in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I want to link all LLVM libraries in my cmake C++ project.

I use `llvm-config --components` to get all the components of LLVM, it gives me:

```
$ llvm-config --components
aarch64 aarch64asmparser aarch64codegen aarch64desc aarch64disassembler aarch64info aarch64utils aggressiveinstcombine all all-targets amdgpu amdgpuasmparser amdgpucodegen amdgpudesc amdgpudisassembler amdgpuinfo amdgpuutils analysis arm armasmparser armcodegen armdesc armdisassembler arminfo armutils asmparser asmprinter binaryformat bitreader bitstreamreader bitwriter bpf bpfasmparser bpfcodegen bpfdesc bpfdisassembler bpfinfo cfguard codegen core coroutines coverage debuginfocodeview debuginfodwarf debuginfogsym debuginfomsf debuginfopdb demangle dlltooldriver dwarflinker engine executionengine frontendopenmp fuzzmutate globalisel hexagon hexagonasmparser hexagoncodegen hexagondesc hexagondisassembler hexagoninfo instcombine instrumentation interpreter ipo irreader jitlink lanai lanaiasmparser lanaicodegen lanaidesc lanaidisassembler lanaiinfo libdriver lineeditor linker lto mc mca mcdisassembler mcjit mcparser mips mipsasmparser mipscodegen mipsdesc mipsdisassembler mipsinfo mirparser msp430 msp430asmparser msp430codegen msp430desc msp430disassembler msp430info native nativecodegen nvptx nvptxcodegen nvptxdesc nvptxinfo objcarcopts object objectyaml option orcerror orcjit passes powerpc powerpcasmparser powerpccodegen powerpcdesc powerpcdisassembler powerpcinfo profiledata remarks riscv riscvasmparser riscvcodegen riscvdesc riscvdisassembler riscvinfo riscvutils runtimedyld scalaropts selectiondag sparc sparcasmparser sparccodegen sparcdesc sparcdisassembler sparcinfo support symbolize systemz systemzasmparser systemzcodegen systemzdesc systemzdisassembler systemzinfo tablegen target textapi transformutils vectorize webassembly webassemblyasmparser webassemblycodegen webassemblydesc webassemblydisassembler webassemblyinfo windowsmanifest x86 x86asmparser x86codegen x86desc x86disassembler x86info x86utils xcore xcorecodegen xcoredesc xcoredisassembler xcoreinfo xray
```

Then I add these components in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG)
llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libraries aarch64 aarch64asmparser aarch64codegen aarch64desc aarch64disassembler aarch64info aarch64utils aggressiveinstcombine all all-targets amdgpu amdgpuasmparser amdgpucodegen amdgpudesc amdgpudisassembler amdgpuinfo amdgpuutils analysis arm armasmparser armcodegen armdesc armdisassembler arminfo armutils asmparser asmprinter binaryformat bitreader bitstreamreader bitwriter bpf bpfasmparser bpfcodegen bpfdesc bpfdisassembler bpfinfo cfguard codegen core coroutines coverage debuginfocodeview debuginfodwarf debuginfogsym debuginfomsf debuginfopdb demangle dlltooldriver dwarflinker engine executionengine frontendopenmp fuzzmutate globalisel hexagon hexagonasmparser hexagoncodegen hexagondesc hexagondisassembler hexagoninfo instcombine instrumentation interpreter ipo irreader jitlink lanai lanaiasmparser lanaicodegen lanaidesc lanaidisassembler lanaiinfo libdriver lineeditor linker lto mc mca mcdisassembler mcjit mcparser mips mipsasmparser mipscodegen mipsdesc mipsdisassembler mipsinfo mirparser msp430 msp430asmparser msp430codegen msp430desc msp430disassembler msp430info native nativecodegen nvptx nvptxcodegen nvptxdesc nvptxinfo objcarcopts object objectyaml option orcerror orcjit passes powerpc powerpcasmparser powerpccodegen powerpcdesc powerpcdisassembler powerpcinfo profiledata remarks riscv riscvasmparser riscvcodegen riscvdesc riscvdisassembler riscvinfo riscvutils runtimedyld scalaropts selectiondag sparc sparcasmparser sparccodegen sparcdesc sparcdisassembler sparcinfo support symbolize systemz systemzasmparser systemzcodegen systemzdesc systemzdisassembler systemzinfo tablegen target textapi transformutils vectorize webassembly webassemblyasmparser webassemblycodegen webassemblydesc webassemblydisassembler webassemblyinfo windowsmanifest x86 x86asmparser x86codegen x86desc x86disassembler x86info x86utils xcore xcorecodegen xcoredesc xcoredisassembler xcoreinfo xray)
```

But it gives me error message:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib/cmake/llvm/LLVM-Config.cmake:281 (message):
  Library 'aarch64' is a direct reference to a target library for an omitted
  target.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  src/CMakeLists.txt:44 (llvm_map_components_to_libnames)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`llvm_map_components_to_libnames` is outdated, so try avoiding it. Adding this code to your CMakeList file should fetch all the llvm libraries at configure time.

```
execute_process(COMMAND llvm-config --libs all
                OUTPUT_VARIABLE llvm_libraries)
```

If you intend to fetch libraries of specific components, just replace `all` with the component names.

Comment: I have no idea that `llvm_map_components_to_libnames` is outdated !

Comment: Hi, I found that there's a cmake variable `${LLVM_LIBRARIES}` is equal to `llvm-config --libs all`. Do you know if there's a variable equal to `llvm-config --system-ilbs all` ?

Comment: Does `llvm-config --system-ilbs all`  in the terminal give you any output?? If it doesn't you don't need it

Comment: It gives me: `-lz -lcurses -lm -lxml2`