# LLVM compiler - undefined references

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, ninja

I'm woriking on a comiler in C++ using **LLVM**. I've already came to the point where I implemented simple numbers and strings. However, when I tried compiling the programm I got a build error.

```
undefined reference to `llvm::BasicBlock::BasicBlock(llvm::LLVMContext&, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Function*, llvm::BasicBlock*)'
undefined reference to `llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::IntegerType*, unsigned long long, bool)'
undefined reference to `llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(llvm::LLVMContext&)'
undefined reference to `llvm::Type::getInt64Ty(llvm::LLVMContext&)'
 undefined reference to `llvm::Function::Create(llvm::FunctionType*, llvm::GlobalValue::LinkageTypes, llvm::Twine const&, llvm::Module&)'
undefined reference to `llvm::outs()'
```

This is not the actual error, just a portion of it. I am getting a bunch of **undefined references**.
Here's the code for my code generator class:

```
#ifndef COMPILER_CODEGENERATION_H
#define COMPILER_CODEGENERATION_H
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Function.h"
#include "ASTNode.h"
namespace COMPILER {

    class CodeGenerator {

        std::shared_ptr<llvm::Module> _module;
        std::shared_ptr<llvm::LLVMContext> _context;
        std::shared_ptr<llvm::IRBuilder<>> _irBuilder;

        llvm::BasicBlock * createBlock(const std::string &blockName, llvm::Function *targetFunc) {
            return llvm::BasicBlock::Create(*_context,blockName, targetFunc);
        }

        llvm::Function * createFunctionPrototype(const std::string &funcName, llvm::FunctionType *funcType) {
            auto proto = llvm::Function::Create(funcType, llvm::Function::ExternalLinkage, funcName, *_module);
            llvm::verifyFunction(*proto);
            return proto;
        }

        void createFunction(const std::string &funcName, llvm::FunctionType *funcType) {
            auto proto = createFunctionPrototype(funcName, funcType);
            auto block = createBlock("entry", proto);
            _irBuilder->SetInsertPoint(block);
        }

    public:
        CodeGenerator(
                const std::shared_ptr<llvm::Module> &module, const std::shared_ptr<llvm::LLVMContext> &context,
                const std::shared_ptr<llvm::IRBuilder<>> &builder
        ) {
            _module = module;
            _context = context;
            _irBuilder = builder;
        }
        // LLVM Value can represent anything. Eg. instructions, strings, numbers ...
        void Compile(const std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Compiler::IExpression>> &statementList) {
            createFunction("main", llvm::FunctionType::get(_irBuilder->getInt32Ty(), false));
            for(auto &expressionStatement: statementList) {
                expressionStatement->codegen(_module, _context, _irBuilder);
            }
        }
    };

    llvm::Value * Compiler::NumberExpressionNode::codegen(
            const std::shared_ptr<llvm::Module> &module,
            const std::shared_ptr<llvm::LLVMContext> &context,
            const std::shared_ptr<llvm::IRBuilder<>> &builder){
        return builder->getInt64(_num);
    }
}
#endif
```

You can ignore the header file and namespace names, because the don't matter.
I am using **Windows 10 and CLion for my project**.
Here are the **commands that I've used to download and compile LLVM**.

```
cd <path_where_the_files_will_be_installed>
git clone --config core.autocrlf=false --depth 1 https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project.git
cd llvm-project
cd llvm
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build . --config Debug --target INSTALL -j <number_of_cores>
```

**Here's my CMakeLists**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(Compiler)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(LLVM REQUIRED CONFIG PATHS Dependencies/llvm/llvm-project/llvm/build NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

include_directories(${LLVM_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_definitions(${LLVM_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(Compiler main.cpp compiler/src/Tokenization.h compiler/src/ASTNode.h compiler/src/Parser.h compiler/src/CodeGeneration.h compiler/src/Compiler.h)

llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader)

target_link_libraries(Compiler ${llvm_libs})
```

[The code hirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDLno.png)

**Earch node in the AST has a codegen() method that is implemented in the CodeGeneration file above.**

**Please can somebody help me with this error?**
Thanks :)

I've already tried **different methods of downloading and compiling LLVM**, but non of them worked.
I also checked for the right LLVM installation and checked my **CMakeLists.txt**

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939671/8925535) help ?

Comment: No, it still doesn't work. I still get **undefined references**. The compilation time is also incredibly slow for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already ran into that issue when using the LLVM infrastructure on Windows and tried to fix it but nothing worked.
Then, I just installed the Ubuntu version of WSL (The Windows Subsystem for Linux) on the Microsoft Store.
Finally, I installed LLVM and Clang with  `apt`, compiled my project and it worked!

Comment: I'll try it and let you know. Thanks!