# Linking against a c/c++ library

Tags: c++, sundials

I have some basic questions regarding linking against a `C/C++` library. I am trying to understand the difference in using the two different usages `-L/usr/local/lib -lm` usage and `/usr/local/lib/libm.a` usage. E.g., when I compile and link an example from the `[SUNDIALS]` [library](http://computation.llnl.gov/projects/sundials-suite-nonlinear-differential-algebraic-equation-solvers), both of the following work

```
gcc -Wall cvRoberts_dns.c -o cvRoberts_dns.exe -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib/ -lsundials_cvode -lsundials_nvecserial -lm
```

OR

```
gcc -Wall cvRoberts_dns.c -o cvRoberts_dns.exe /usr/local/lib/libsundials_cvode.a /usr/local/lib/libsundials_nvecserial.a
```

However, to compile and link an example from the [library](http://sbml.org/Software/libSBML) `[libsbml]`, the following works

```
g++ -Wall readSBML.cpp -o readSBML.exe -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lsbml
```

but the this does not

```
g++ -Wall readSBML.cpp -o readSBML.exe /usr/local/lib/libsbml.a
```

If required, I can post the complete error message I get, but the last line of the message is as follows

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My questions are as follows:

1. In the second style of linking (of the first example), there is no information regarding where to find the `include` files (header files), how does the compiler know the information supplied in `-I/usr/local/include` which is provided in the first style of the first example?
2. In the second style of first example there is no `/usr/local/lib/libm.a` (it actually gives an error message that `libm.a` cannot be found if I try to include it), then why `-lm` is required in the first style?
3. How do I compile the second example in the second style (i.e., using `/usr/local/lib/libsbml.a`)? I do see that there are files - `libsbml.a` and `libsbml-static.a` in the `/usr/local/lib` folder, but none of them work.

If it helps, I am on an `OS X` machine.

I would be very thankful if any one could help in this regard.

Just an update - I tried

```
g++ -Wall readSBML.cpp -o readSBML.exe /usr/local/lib/libsbml.5.dylib
```

and that compiled and linked just fine.

Thanks
SN

Comment: I have seen questions about similar error messages in Xcode. You may want to search for it first.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18973042/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-x86-64-on-qtcreator-project

Comment: Did you want to link to a static library or to a dylib?

Comment: Could it be that you must add some other framework?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis - Ideally, I want to link to the static library. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**In general**

- The `-L` option is meant to find where the libraries themselves are. Each library is a collection of one or more object code (machine language) files. There is no need to find the include files.
- The `-I` option has nothing to with linker, it helps the compiler resolve the header files used in your driver programme( eg Roberts_dns.c). This happens during the pre-processing stage.

> In the second style of linking (of the first example), there is no
>   information regarding where to find the include files (header files),..

If the compilation worked as you expected,it may be because `/usr/local/include` is in the default include path for `gcc`. To check the default include path for `gcc` do `gcc -xc -E -v -`.

> In the second style of first example there is no
>   /usr/local/lib/libm.a(it actually gives an error message that libm.a
>   cannot be found if I try to include it), then why -lm is required in
>   the first style?

In Linux, some libraries like `libc.a` are directly linked to your execultable by default while `libm.a` is not. In Mac (your environment), though, libm is directly link to the executable by default. So you don't have to explicitly link it. It is less likely that `libm.a` is located in `/usr/local/lib/`. So you got an error. But why link it in the first place?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I do understand the `-I` and `-L` flags, however, I don't understand why they are not required in the second style. I did run the command - `gcc -xc -E -v`, the output is pasted below - `Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.5.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin`. Thank you.